# replace filter and map with reduce es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to avoid chaining with filter and map, but why my reduce returned undefined?

```
const data = [{
        value: "moto",
        passed: true
    },{
        value: "boat",
        passed: false
    }, {
        value: "car",
        passed: true
    }]

    // expected ['moto', 'car']
    // using filter and map
    data.filter(obj => obj.passed).map(obj => obj.value)
```

What's wrong?
`data.reduce((accum, obj) => obj.checked && [...accum, obj.value], [])`

Comment: It is "passed" not "checked" on your data.

Comment: You need a ternary operator in your `reduce` callback, not `&&`. Imagine what you return when `obj.passed` is false... it should be `accum`, but instead you return `false`.

Comment: What's wrong with chaining `filter` and `map`?

Comment: @Denis - you run similar loop 2 times instead of one.
So it might, for example, take 4sec instead of 2sec.

Comment: The solution with `reduce` would be this: `data.reduce((accum, obj) => obj.passed ? [...accum, obj.value] : accum, [])`. But there is nothing wrong with using `filter` and `map`.

Comment: @pbialy I disagree. The `filter` and `map` version is much cleaner and expressive and it's composable. And the resulting performance are not like you wrote at all.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato if you don't know what is reduce, then yes. reduce has better performances, you don't want to loop through big list of array twice, or more..

Comment: @Denis I made a small fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwjane9z/6/ and results are very shocking - looks like in this case filter + map has much better performance.  Like 100 times better. It's ... really confusing tbh.

Comment: Can someone explain this? Or maybe I should make separate question for it...

Comment: But then I changed assignment method in `reduce` it looks faster now: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwjane9z/8/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 (accum, obj) => obj.checked && [...accum, obj.value]
```

does not return the filtered list, in case the object is not checked.

```
(accum, obj) => {
  if (obj.checked) accum.push(obj.value)
  return accum;
}
```

as reducer function will do that.

or to keep it as a oneliner, to not maintain readability:

```
(accum, obj) => obj.checked ? [...accum, obj.value] : accum;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{value: "moto",passed: true}, {value: "boat",passed: false}, {value: "car",passed: true}];
const result = data.reduce((a, { passed: p, value: v}) => p ? (a.push(v), a) : a, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 for using `(a.push(c.value), a)`, that removes the immutable nature of `[...a, c.value]`, but since that is a simple reducer its ok in favor of performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not returning anything if obj.passed = `false`. Updated below. Pls check

```js
const data = [{
        value: "moto",
        passed: true
    },{
        value: "boat",
        passed: false
    }, {
        value: "car",
        passed: true
    }]

console.log(data.reduce((accum, obj) => 
              obj.passed 
                ? accum.concat(obj.value) 
                : accum
           , []))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const list =[
  {
    name:'Raj'
    ,
    age:40
  },{
    name:'Raj 2'
    ,
    age:20
  },{
    name:'Raj 3'
    ,
    age:30
  },{
    name:'Raj 4'
    ,
    age:20
  }]
  
  const result = list.reduce((a, c) => c.age>25 ? (a.push(c.name), a) : a, []);
  console.log(result)
```