# Is reduce faster than filter + map in general?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Inspired by this question:

[replace filter and map with reduce es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373863/replace-filter-and-map-with-reduce-es6?noredirect=1)

I decided to test if `reduce` is faster than `filter` plus `map` on given example.

I made a fiddle:

```js
var data = Array(10 ** 4).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
  return {
    checked: Math.random() < 0.5,
    val: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
  }
})

f1 = () => {
  t0 = performance.now();
  data.filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.val)
  t1 = performance.now();
  // console.log("filter plus map took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  document.getElementById('filterPlusMap').innerText = t1 - t0;
}

f2 = () => {
  t0 = performance.now();
  data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return curr.checked ? [...prev, curr.val] : prev 
  }, [])
  t1 = performance.now();
  // console.log("reduce took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  document.getElementById('reduce').innerText = t1 - t0;
}

f1();
f2();
```

```html
<div>Filter plus map: <span id='filterPlusMap'></span> milliseconds</div>
<div>Reduce: <span id='reduce'></span> milliseconds</div>
```

and it turned out that `reduce` is like 100 times worse...

But then I changed assignment method in `reduce` and it turned out to be better  than filter+map in next fiddle (like 4 times better):

```js
var data = Array(10 ** 6).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
  return {
    checked: Math.random() < 0.5,
    val: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
  }
})

f1 = () => {
  t0 = performance.now();
  data.filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.val)
  t1 = performance.now();
  // console.log("filter plus map took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  document.getElementById('filterPlusMap').innerText = t1 - t0;
}

f2 = () => {
  t0 = performance.now();
  data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return curr.checked ? (prev.push(curr.val), prev) : prev 
  }, [])
  t1 = performance.now();
  // console.log("reduce took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  document.getElementById('reduce').innerText = t1 - t0;
}

f1();
f2();
```

```html
<div>Filter plus map: <span id='filterPlusMap'></span> milliseconds</div>
<div>Reduce: <span id='reduce'></span> milliseconds</div>
```

Can someone pls:

1. Explain why it changed so much between the fiddles? I.e. - why `(prev.push(curr.val), prev)` is so much better? And should it be used?
2. Tell if `reduce` should be always prefered over filter+map
   ?

Comment: Be wary of the term "faster". This is almost always subjective

Comment: Well `[...prev, curr.val]` will be making a new array for EVERY element. It's bound to be slower than just a `.push`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Explain why it changed so much between the fiddles? I.e. - why `(prev.push(curr.val), prev)` is so much better? And should it be used?

`(arr.push(val), arr)` is much faster than `[...arr, val]` as the latter copies the whole `arr` array into a new array, giving the `reduce` operation a *O(n²)* time complexity. The first only has to add 1 element to the existing `arr`, ... this gives a *O(n)* time complexity to the whole `reduce` operation.

> Tell if `reduce` should be always preferred over `filter`+`map` ?

No, this really depends on the logic to be applied and what requirements you have in terms of performance. And readability also counts: `filter` and `map` tend to be a bit more readable (understandable) than `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :) Could you pls tell me one more thing - in `(prev.push(curr.val), prev)` we are preventing the 1st to return anything and instead we return the 2nd, but after 1st is executed. How it's called? I would like to read something about this.

Comment: Look for ["comma operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: @pbialy it's called [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) - is that what you're asking?